# Sum of the number 1 to 10000 using MPI_Scatter

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I'm currently developing a piece of code that has 10 processes. Process 0 reads a total of 10000 (from lab7.csv). Afterwards, it distributes the array to all of the processes. In order to do this, I created an array named "intArray[10000]" that is shared by all processes. 49893236 is the correct summation.

The following code makes use of 10 processors to compute the sum of numbers ranging from 1 to 1000. This aggregate is calculated by each of the processors, and the results are shown on the screen.

As a result, a follower error is shown.

I didn't figure out what the problem is. Please assist me in this matter.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        int rank, nodes;
        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nodes);
        MPI_Status status;

        int intArray[10000];
        int subIntArray[1000];

        if(rank == 0) {
                // Substitute the full file path for the string file_path
                FILE *fp = fopen("./lab7.csv", "r");

                int i = 0;
                int num;

                if (!fp) {
                        printf("Can't open file\n");
                } else {
                        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) > 0)
                        {
                                intArray[i] = num;
                                i++;
                        }
                        // Close the file
                        fclose(fp);
                }
        }

        MPI_Scatter(intArray, 10000, MPI_INT, subIntArray, 1000, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        int ans = 0;
        int total = 0;

        int start = rank * 1000;
        int end = start + 999;

        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                ans = ans + subIntArray[i];
        }

        if(rank != 0) {
                MPI_Ssend(&ans, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        } else {
                total = ans;
                for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                        MPI_Recv(&ans, 1, MPI_INT, j, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                        total += ans;
                }
                printf("Total is %d\n", total);
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
}
```

The PBS Job file as followers,

```
#PBS -l nodes=2
#PBS -l walltime=00:02:00
#PBS -l select=5
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
NPROC=10
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
MPISIZE=$NPROC
MPIPROG=`basename $PBS_JOBNAME .pbs`
echo 'Running MPI program' $MPIPROG 'on' $MPISIZE 'processes'
echo 'Started at' `date`
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
(time mpirun -n $MPISIZE ./$MPIPROG) 2>&1
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'Finished at' `date`
```

This is the error message that is shown on the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of `MPI_Scatter` is a bit different than the one you have.

You say: I have `NTOT` data elements and I want to send them to `NODECOUNT` nodes so I want each node to process `NTOT / NODECOUNT` of data. This doesn't work if `NTOT` is *not* an exact multiple of `NODECOUNT`

But, `MPI_Scatter` is oriented the other way: I have `NPER` number of elements that each node should process, and `NODECOUNT` nodes, so the total number of elements is `NTOT = NPER * NODECOUNT` This is how the manpage example shows it.

You want to give a count of `NPER` to `MPI_Scatter` and *not* `NTOT`. And, you want the send and receive counts to match.

Also, because `MPI_Scatter` does the split for you, the slave nodes should *not* use `start/end` as you calculated, but always do:

```
start = 0;
end = NPER - 1;
```

---

Also, in your code ...

You were indexing into `subIntArray` as if you could access `0-9999` instead of `0-999`, so you were going beyond the end of the array and had UB (undefined behavior)

It's a bit shaky to hardwire `10`, `100`, `1000` everywhere. Better to use the some `#define` and the actual node code `nodes`

And, you *assume* you have 10000 valid input data elements rather than calculating this based on your `i` index variable when you do `fscanf`

---

Here is the corrected code, with some extra debug code I used.

I used preprocessor conditionals to denote old vs new code (e.g.):

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Also, I didn't have your data files, so I had to synthesize the input data.

Anyway, here it is:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int rank;
int nodes;
FILE *xfdbg;

#define dbgprtattr(_lvl) \
    __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,_lvl,_lvl + 1)))

#if DEBUG || _USE_ZPRT_
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    _dbgprt(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

void dbgprtattr(1)
_dbgprt(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char buf[10000];
    char *bp = buf;

    bp += sprintf(bp,"[%d] ",rank);

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    bp += vsprintf(bp,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    fputs(buf,xfdbg);
    fflush(xfdbg);
}

//#define NTOT      10000
//#define NPER      (NTOT / nodes)

int
main()
{

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nodes);
    MPI_Status status;

    char logf[100];
    sprintf(logf,"log_%2.2d",rank);
    xfdbg = fopen(logf,"w");

#if 0
    int BIGSIZE = nodes * 1000;
    int NPER = NTOT / nodes;
#else
    //int NPER = 1000;
    int NPER = 50;
    //int NTOT = NPER * nodes;
#endif

    int val;
    int truetotal = 0;

#if 0
    int intArray[NTOT];
#else
    int intArray[nodes][NPER];
#endif

#if 1
    int subIntArray[NPER];
#else
    int subIntArray[NTOT];
#endif

    if (rank == 0) {
#if 0
        // Substitute the full file path for the string file_path
        FILE *fp = fopen("./lab7.csv", "r");

        int i = 0;
        int num;

        if (!fp) {
            printf("Can't open file\n");
        }
        else {
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) > 0) {
                intArray[i] = num;
                i++;
            }
            // Close the file
            fclose(fp);
        }
#endif

        for (int nd = 0;  nd < nodes;  ++nd) {
            for (int i = 0;  i < NPER;  ++i) {
                val = (nd << 16) | i;
                intArray[nd][i] = val;
                truetotal += val;
            }
        }
    }

    dbgprt("main: hello\n");
#if 0
    MPI_Scatter(intArray, NTOT, MPI_INT,
        subIntArray, NPER, MPI_INT,
        0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    dbgprt("main: post\n");
#endif
#if 1
    MPI_Scatter(intArray, NPER, MPI_INT,
        subIntArray, NPER, MPI_INT,
        0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    dbgprt("main: post\n");
#endif
#if 0
    MPI_Scatter(intArray, NTOT, MPI_INT,
        subIntArray, NTOT, MPI_INT,
        0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    dbgprt("main: post\n");
#endif

    //sleep(10);

    int ans = 0;
    int total = 0;

#if 0
    int start = rank * NPER;
    int end = start + NPER - 1;
#else
    int start = 0;
    int end = NPER - 1;
#endif

    dbgprt("main: START start=%d end=%d\n",start,end);

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        dbgprt("main: DATA i=%d sub=%8.8X\n",i,subIntArray[i]);
        ans = ans + subIntArray[i];
    }

    dbgprt("main: loopdone ans=%d\n",ans);

    if (rank != 0) {
        MPI_Ssend(&ans, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else {
        total = ans;
        for (int j = 1; j < nodes; j++) {
            MPI_Recv(&ans, 1, MPI_INT, j, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            total += ans;
        }
        printf("Total is %d\n", total);
        printf("Total is %d (TRUE)\n", truetotal);

    }

    fclose(xfdbg);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I'm sorry . I didn't get it. It's pretty hard for me to absorb but I'm trying.

Comment: Not to worry. Think about it a bit more and go over it a few times. If you're still stuck, you could comment here with what you [now] understand and what you're still having trouble with. I may be able to enhance/expand my explanation or add better comments to the code to help